# Different count for compressed file listing vs directory listing

Tags: ls, tar, compression

I was taking a backup of a folder, where I used the following command :

`sudo tar -zcvf www.tar.gz /var/www/`

It successfully compressed, just for verifying the number of files in the compressed archive, and the directory I ran the following commands :

`sudo tar -ztvf www.tar.gz | wc -l`  -> `186364`

`ls -R /var/www | wc -l` -> `196440`

How come the count is different, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the output without piping to `wc` to see the difference

```
$ ls -R www | cat
www:
dir1
dir2
file1

www/dir1:
file1

www/dir2:
file1
file2
$ ls -R www | wc -l
11
```

And

```
$ tar xvfz www.tar.gz
www/
www/dir1/
www/dir1/file1
www/dir2/
www/dir2/file1
www/dir2/file2
www/file1
$ tar xvfz www.tar.gz |wc -l
7
```

`ls -R`  just produces some more output.

Comment: Yup, never realized that ls adds new lines between folders.

Comment: Just verified the number of files using `find /var/www/ -type 'd' -o -type 'f' | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

`ls -R` puts some extra empty lines in the output which causes the count to increase.

You can test it by running the command `ls -R` without piping it to `wc -l`

Comment: Thanks, yup that was the problem. Would upvote, however, still require 15 rep.

Comment: @AaditiSharma: Its okay aaditi :P

Answer (score -1):

Use the `tree` command

```
tree -i |tail
```

this will give you the number of folders and files in particular folder.